# How to add buy now button on product page to checkout page with the quantities

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, addtocart

I´m not a programmer but I'm running my shop with Magento, I tried to use the suggestion below to create a **'Buy Now'** button and works fine.

But add only 1 unit of the product.

How can I do to add the quantities as the client needs?

Suggestion of code:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check out') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index/') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?></span></span></button>
 <script>
 function setcheckoutLocation(location,chkout)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = chkout;
                }
             });
}
</script>
```

Today my original code is bellow.

Thanks!

```
?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart left-side">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="paypal-wrapper"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, I tried the code bellow and did not work with the quantities:

```
    ?>
    <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <div class="add-to-cart left-side">
            <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                <div class="qty-wrapper">
                    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check out') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index/') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="paypal-wrapper"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<script>
 function setcheckoutLocation(location,chkout)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = chkout;
                }
             });
}
</script>
```

Comment: After adding the `<input type="text" name="qty" />` it must work. Are you still facing the same error?

Comment: Sorry did not understand. Where I need to add this?
The last code is the original, I changed the line <button type="button" for the suggestion, and paste the script. But did not add the quantity right.

Comment: I edit the original post, and put the code I was at the end. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the qty parameter in your **getAddToCartUrl($_product)** function.

Update your code as given below.

```
<?php $data['qty'] = 3; ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check out') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product, $data) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index/') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?></span></span></button>

 <script>
 function setcheckoutLocation(location,chkout)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = chkout;
                }
             });
}
</script>
```

It will add 3 quantity. You can enter your desired quantity to `$data['qty']`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try it. But to add the quantity the client needs, the correct code should be the code below? To get the amount from the box.
<?php $data['qty'] = qty; ?>